# How to create a menu like WeChat under the navigation bar item?

Tags: ios, swift, menu

Look at the picture:

[image]

I have tried to use a translucent UIViewController to create this menu, but it is not a good way.Tell me how to create a menu above.

Comment: What about this? https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu

Comment: kxmenu is good, but it used objective c,have it a swift version?